# JavaFX WebView white page (not loading)

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I get a white page after filling in some forms and uploading a photo on https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/index.html. I use JavaFX’s WebView to load the website. Everything works fine until I hit the photo upload button.

Filling in the form works perfectly fine with other browsers and was successful with Chrome, Firefox and Safari. Therefore I suspect it’s something specific to JavaFX’s WebView.

I tried ruling out any bugs by writing only the WebView part. Yet the white page is still displayed.

```java
public class SimpleTest extends Application {          
    public static void main(String[] args) {         
        launch(args);     
    }             

@Override     
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {         
    WebView webView = new WebView();            webView.getEngine().load("https://indianvisaonline.gov.in/visa/indianVisaReg.jsp");              

    Scene scene = new Scene(webView);         
    Stage stage = new Stage();         
    stage.setScene(scene);         
    stage.show();     
    }     
}
```

**JavaFX WebEngine’s HTML 5 support**

I notice the lack of HTML5 support compared to other browsers. JavaFX’s WebView (WebEngine) scores just 275 out of 555 points, whereas other browsers score way better. The things that I feel can break something is the lack of Web Cryptography API, Database storage, File Reading or limited ECMAScript 6 support. Yet I have no idea how to test this?

**Testing with Firebug Lite**

When embedding Firebug, something weird happens. Instead of showing a blank white page, it redirects me to the homepage. So Firebug can’t help me here either.

**Debug**

Trying to find something in the logs I added: -Djavax.net.debug=all. However this doesn’t return any errors either (like HTTPS related).

At this point I’d by happy with any advice!

Answer (score 2):

On a project with JavaFX Webview we found the following useful:

```
    webView.setContextMenuEnabled(true);
    webView.getEngine().setOnError(event -> System.out.println(event.getMessage()));
    webView.getEngine().setOnAlert(event -> System.out.println(event.getData()));

    // local error console
    com.sun.javafx.webkit.WebConsoleListener.setDefaultListener(
            (webview, message, lineNumber, sourceId) -> System.out
                    .println("Console: [" + sourceId + ":" + lineNumber + "] " + message));

    // Firebug lite
    webView.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(
            (ChangeListener<State>) (ov, oldState, newState) -> {
                if (newState == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                    webView.getEngine().executeScript(
                            "if (!document.getElementById('FirebugLite')){E = document['createElement' + 'NS'] && document.documentElement.namespaceURI;E = E ? document['createElement' + 'NS'](E, 'script') : document['createElement']('script');E['setAttribute']('id', 'FirebugLite');E['setAttribute']('src', 'https://getfirebug.com/' + 'firebug-lite.js' + '#startOpened');E['setAttribute']('FirebugLite', '4');(document['getElementsByTagName']('head')[0] || document['getElementsByTagName']('body')[0]).appendChild(E);E = new Image;E['setAttribute']('src', 'https://getfirebug.com/' + '#startOpened');}");
                }
            });
    webView.getEngine().locationProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> System.out.println(newValue));
```

Also it seems the browser that behaves similarly to Webview is Safari. If something doesn't work on Safari it generally doesn't on Webview. Safari has better tools for development however.

Also you might pay attention to popups and sites that open new windows, this must be handled manually with Webview.